# CSS equivalent of `DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo()` (C# - UWP)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, xaml

I am making a StyleSheet of Windows Fluent Design System which has **almost** all Fluency features. And fluency has a navigation transition effect:

```
void Page_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page), pageId, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
}
```

The `DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo()` is the effect I want to recreate in CSS.
How do I do it? I want it to be as real as possible please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AnimationMetrics API to get the exact keysplines used by the transition, and then re-create in CSS.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AnimationMetrics

(It will be a combination of scale and opacity).